# JMenuItem and ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenuitem

Haveing problem with my JMenuItem and ActionListener, I'm trying to make a JMenuItem that can select numbers of players in a game but my `PlayerAlt[i].addActionListener(players);` code gives me an error that "players cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
    String[] Players = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    JMenu pmenu = new JMenu("Players");
    final JMenuItem[] PlayerAlt = new JMenuItem[Players.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < PlayerAlt.length; i++) {
      PlayerAlt[i] = new JMenuItem(Players[i]);
      pmenu.add(PlayerAlt[i]);
      PlayerAlt[i].addActionListener(players);
    }
    ActionListener players = new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayerAlt.length; i++) {
          if (e.getSource() == PlayerAlt[i]) {
        Gamerside.add(s1);
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `players` is declared after you want to use it. Thus it can not be resolved.

Move the `players` declaration above the loop

```
ActionListener players = new ActionListener() {
      ......
};
for (int i = 0; i < PlayerAlt.length; i++) {
    .....
    PlayerAlt[i].addActionListener(players);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `players` is declared **after** you try to use it (two lines later), so it is does not exist the moment you try to use it.

For clarification:

```
int b = 4;
b += a; //Error, a does not exist yet..
int a = 2; //...because it is declared here
```